# How do I test an Android app?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and would like to know how Android apps are tested.

I have created a very simple app that allows a user to draw, and save, send, clear the drawing--how would I go about testing this?

Comment: Here's a good place to start.  FYI: the search term you're looking for is "unit testing" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522312/best-practices-for-unit-testing-android-apps

Answer (score 3):

Android apps are tested by the same range of methodologies as anything else, including unit and functional testing. There are a number of options, some obvious ones include:

- The [`android.test` package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/package-summary.html) that ships with the SDK, containing a bunch of classes with common test functionality, as well as `android.test.mock` which contains what you'd expect.
- ["loquacious-droid"](http://code.google.com/p/loquacious-droid/) for testing in a more human-readable manner (sort of).
- ["robotium"](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) provide a Selenium-like test environment for black-box testing.